# Django get objects from url slug not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to make it so that I can show only briefs with the slug name as the category, however it does not work.

At the minute I can only use it by showing all briefs using .objects.all() however this is not suitable for my desired use case.

Do i need a slug field in the brief section too?

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
        verbose_name = 'category'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('browse')


class Brief(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    brandname = models.CharField(max_length=28)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('homepage')
```

Urls.py

```
 path('browse/categories/<slug:catslug>/', views.postsinthecategory, name = 'catslug'
```

views.py

```
def postsinthecategory(request, catslug):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    brief = Brief.objects.all()
    if catslug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = catslug)
        brief = Brief.objects.get(category=catslug)
    template = 'users/categoryposts.html'
    context = {'categories': categories, 'brief': brief, 'category': category}
    return render(request, template,context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__slug` to filter on the related model's `slug` field. Use `filter` instead of `get`, because you want a queryset that can contain more than `brief`. I would rename `brief` to `briefs` in your view to make that clearer.

```
briefs = Brief.objects.filter(category__slug=catslug)
```

Or, since you fetched the category on the previous line, you could do:

```
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug = catslug)
briefs = Brief.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Comment: It should be `filter` not `get` because there can be multiple briefs for each category. Fixed now.